# How to make GANTT ListViewWebPartJSGrid_leftpane_mainTable read-only

Tags: jquery

How do I make the ListViewWebPartJSGrid_leftpane_mainTable  section on GANTT charts fully read only?

I have tried all of the following code, but the fill handle control is still active. How do I turn off the fill handle?

```
$("[id$=ListViewWebPartJSGrid]").attr("readonly",true);
    jQuery("th[role='gridcell']").css("pointer-events:none;");
$("[id$=ListViewWebPartJSGrid_leftpane_mainTable]").attr("readonly",true);
$("[id$=ListViewWebPartJSGrid_leftpane_mainTable]").css("pointer-events:none;");

jQuery("td[role='gridcell']").css("pointer-events:none;");
jQuery("td[role='gridcell']").removeAttr('onclick'); 
jQuery("td[role='gridcell']").prop( "disabled", true );


var whatidpart = "_ListViewWebPartJSGrid_leftpane_mainTable";
var thisid = $("[id$=" + whatidpart + "]").attr("id");
    var thiscolumn = $('#' + thisid + " th[role='columnheader']").each(function () {

    $(thiscolumn).css("pointer-events:none;");
    $(thiscolumn).children().css("pointer-events:none;");
    $(thiscolumn).removeAttr('onclick');
    $(thiscolumn).children().removeAttr('onclick');
    $(thiscolumn).prop( "disabled", true );
    $(thiscolumn).children().prop( "disabled", true );
    $(thiscolumn).attr("readonly",true);
    $(thiscolumn).children().attr("readonly",true);
});
```